# Why is Jade not displaying date value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

The Jade template is:

```
block content
    h1= title
    div.container
        if notes
            each item in notes
                div
                    h3 Date: #{item.date}
                    p=item.content
        else
            div No notes
```

However only `title` and `item.content` are being rendered, the `item.date` just renders empty `<h3>` tags. The object being passed to Jade is:

```
{
 'title': 'Notes', 
 'notes': [{"content":"A note","date":"2014-03-30T12:03:50.096Z"}]
}
```

Which I am getting from:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/notes');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Error in connecting to MongoDb: ' + err);
});
db.once('open', function() {
    Notes
        .find()
        .select('-_id')
        .exec(function(err, retrievedNotes) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(retrievedNotes));
        res.render('index', {'title': 'Notes', 'notes': retrievedNotes});
        mongoose.disconnect();
    });
});
```

However only:

```
<h1>Notes</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <h3>Date: </h3>
        <p>A note</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

is rendered.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the `jade` code. For me it runs correctly.

Comment: @Pio Yeah, I tried it on the online jade compiler and it _did_ work... Mabey its something to do with the Node.js code - have added that to question

Comment: The weird thing is that I `console.log`ed the variable holding values and it looked fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some issue with opening the database connection and starting the server. The below code works for me fine.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
Notes
    .find()
    .select('-_id')
    .exec(function(err, retrievedNotes) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(retrievedNotes));
        res.render('index', {
            'title': 'Notes',
            'notes': retrievedNotes
        });
    });

});

db.once('open', function() {
   console.log('connected to db')
   http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
       console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
   });
});
```

Also you should `mongoose.disconnect();` when you're shutting down your server, since if you disconnect in the route handler then you'll not be able to handle other requests, because you open your `db` connection only once.

Answer (score 0):

I realised it was because the field I created in the database schema was `dateCreated` not `date`! All I had to do was change `#{item.date}` to `#{item.dateCreated}`.